typeorm repository not found on dev
I have a project which have following scipt
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ts-node build.ts",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "start": "node -r module-alias/register ./dist --env=production",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "test": "nodemon --config ./spec/nodemon.json"
  }

after build and running
npm run start

This is working fine, but when I try running on dev, it says no repository found
npm run start:dev

I have no knowledge of typeorm, just trying to run the project,
any help,
highly apprecited.
Thanks
